# Magento 2: how to save a new instance of a custom model to the database (INSERT INTO instead of UPDATE)

Tags: magento2, database, model, save

I have created a model and a repository to save the model, the only functions I can find in the model->getResource() are save, load and delete. The save function always uses an UPDATE statement, so how can I save a new instance of my model to the database?

I am a bit confused because while searching for a solution I could only find people who have the opposite problem, their save function uses an INSERT INTO statement instead of UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento save and update inside save method in resource model class. [Goto here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php#L380)
Method looks like:

```
public function save(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
{
    if ($object->isDeleted()) {
        return $this->delete($object);
    }

    $this->beginTransaction();

    try {
        if (!$this->isModified($object)) {
            $this->processNotModifiedSave($object);
            $this->commit();
            $object->setHasDataChanges(false);
            return $this;
        }
        $object->validateBeforeSave();
        $object->beforeSave();
        if ($object->isSaveAllowed()) {
            $this->_serializeFields($object);
            $this->_beforeSave($object);
            $this->_checkUnique($object);
            $this->objectRelationProcessor->validateDataIntegrity($this->getMainTable(), $object->getData());
            if ($this->isObjectNotNew($object)) {
                $this->updateObject($object);
            } else {
                $this->saveNewObject($object);
            }
            $this->unserializeFields($object);
            $this->processAfterSaves($object);
        }
        $this->addCommitCallback([$object, 'afterCommitCallback'])->commit();
        $object->setHasDataChanges(false);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->rollBack();
        $object->setHasDataChanges(true);
        throw $e;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Actually following line perform update or insert

```
if ($this->isObjectNotNew($object)) {
    $this->updateObject($object);
} else {
    $this->saveNewObject($object);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, apparently isObjectNotNew() checks if the object has an ID, and my model does not use an identity column so the objects always had an ID when I set their data

Comment: @Kaascroissant Thankyou for detailing your discovery - I also found that because I was making a custom table with a column subset if I kept the id column from the superset table that ResourceModel was recognising it as an update even though the record didn't exist in the subset table